# CosmosDB BulkExecutor not showing FailedImports

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the library Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor with version 2.4.1-preview in one of my project. The documentation explains a property named FailedImports here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.bulkexecutor.bulkimport.bulkimportresponse?view=azure-dotnet
But I am not getting this property as part of library.

Comment: That BulkImportResponse type is from the official, non-preview branch (1.8.8)

Comment: Mine is a .net core application and it is not allowing me to add the version 1.8.8 of bulk executor. It is giving error saying The type 'DocumentClient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=2.5.1.0. And this is a .net framework dependency

Comment: You can then go with Mark's comment. Also, this article will help if you were already using Bulk Executor V2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-migrate-from-bulk-executor-library

Answer (score 0):

This library was deprecated in November last year. Please use the latest Cosmos DB SDK which includes Bulk Support. You can read more details and some examples in our [Bulk support blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/)

You can also find more samples in our [.NET SDK repo bulk samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/BulkSupport)

Thanks.